# Trying to fill part of a column based on a cell

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI I have three columns and I am trying to add a fourth. With these three columns I am trying to create a forth that pulls in a "Y" for each PO Number that has a row that says "New" in the status column.
In my example I am showing three different PO's that have different rows with different statuses. Two of my PO's have at least one row with a "New" status. I would expect to see a "Y" for all the rows that contain those PO's.

| PO Number | Status | Contains "New" Status | New Status? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | New | Y | Y |
| 10000 | Closed |  | Y |
| 10000 | Open |  | Y |
| 10000 | New | Y | Y |
| 10000 | Waiting |  | Y |
| 10001 | New | Y | Y |
| 10001 | Open |  | Y |
| 10001 | New | Y | Y |
| 10002 | Waiting |  |  |
| 10002 | Open |  |  |
| 10002 | Closed |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used both for DAX Calculated columns and measures

```
Column2= CALCULATE(MAX('Table 1'[Contains "New" Status]),ALLEXCEPT('Table 1','Table 1'[PO Number]),'Table 1'[Status]="New")
```

[image: Solution]

[image: Solution]